# How to display body and headers before sending POST request?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I use a library `requests`:

```
import requests

r = requests.post(url=url, data=data, headers=headers, auth=(self.api_key, ''))
```

How to display body and headers before sending POST request? or display full request how it is sent?

Because server returns 400 HTTP with message Bad Request. So I need to see what is sending.

When I do:

```
print r.request.body
```

It returns:

```
subcategory_id=1378&category_id=45&features=id&features=value&features=id&features=value&features=id&features=value&offer_type=18979
```

But body is:

```
data = {
            'category_id': category_id,
            'subcategory_id': subcategory_id,
            'offer_type': offer_type,
            'features': [
                {"id": "7", "value": "12900"},
                {"id": "12", "value": "Title adadadadasdasdadad"},
                {"id": "16", "value": ["3360383821"]}
          ]
        }
```

How is it possible?

Comment: Alternatively, if possible, you can use a `curl -v -X POST -H ... -d <data> url` and see the interaction between the server. Or [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) if you prefer GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`r.request` is the corresponding `Request` object you need.

```
import requests

r = requests.post(url=url, data=data, headers=headers, auth=(self.api_key, ''))
print r.request.headers
print r.request.body
```

You can do it after you get the response, everything will still be there. See [PreparedRequest](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests).

As for your edited question, use `requests.post(url=url, json=data, ...)`.

Comment: Can you see my question again?

Answer (score 0):

```
r.url
r.headers
r.body
```

should work in the terminal, probably have to print it in a script

You also don't need "url=url", you can just leave it as "url", assuming that's where you've stored the base you're trying to post to.

Comment: Bad, it is returns only url, not full request

Comment: Right, add in the r.headers and r.body command to see the rest of it

Comment: see my question again

Answer (score 0):

You can use portal [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org) for test. It sends back all your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lower-level `Request` and `Session` objects of the requests library. Taken whole-cloth from requests' documentation:

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests

> Prepared Requests
>
> Whenever you receive a Response object from an API call or a Session
> call, the request attribute is actually the PreparedRequest that was
> used. In some cases you may wish to do some extra work to the body or
> headers (or anything else really) before sending a request. The simple
> recipe for this is the following:
>
> ````
> s = Session()
>
> req = Request('POST', url, data=data, headers=headers) prepped =
> req.prepare()
>
> # do something with prepped.body prepped.body = 'No, I want exactly this as the body.'
>
> # do something with prepped.headers del prepped.headers['Content-Type']
>
> resp = s.send(prepped,
>     stream=stream,
>     verify=verify,
>     proxies=proxies,
>     cert=cert,
>     timeout=timeout )
>
> print(resp.status_code) ```
> ````